# Passing values to atexit

Tags: c++, boost-bind, atexit

I want to push a series of clean up functions as they are needed. I was using atexit to do this for one cleanup function without any parameters, but I am not sure how to expand this approach to more then one clean up function. I am not very familiar with boost::bind, but assumed it would be a good idea as that is how I binded my functions to threads...

In c++ I am trying to get the following to work:

Function Definition

```
static void closeAnimation(string prefix="");// static member of fileWriter
```

Code:

```
atexit(boost::bind(fileWriter::closeAnimation, "0")); // I want to first prefix to be "0"
```

The error:

```
cannot convert ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(std::basic_string<char>), boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<const char*> > >’ to ‘void (*)()’ for argument
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "1 line solution without complicating your code".

The worst solution is to store that parameter in a global variable, and retrieve it in the `atexit` handler

Since you're using C++, the destructor of a static variable could also serve as an `atexit` handler. Then you can pass parameter at the constructor of that static variable for parametrization, e.g.

```
struct AtExitAnimationCloser
{
    const char* _which_param;

    AtExitAnimationCloser(const char* which_param) : _which_param(which_param) {}
    ~AtExitAnimationCloser() { FileWriter::closeAnimation(_which_param); }
};

void f()
{
    printf("entering f\n");

    static AtExitAnimationCloser s0 ("0"); // registers closeAnimation("0") at exit
    static AtExitAnimationCloser s1 ("1"); // registers closeAnimation("1") at exit

    printf("leaving f\n");
}
```

Demonstration: http://www.ideone.com/bfYnY

Note that static variables are bound to their name, so you cannot say

```
for (it = vecs.begin(); it != vecs.end(); ++ it)
{
   static AtExitAnimationCloser s (*it);
}
```

to call `atexit` for all the content. But you could make the static variable itself take whole range

```
static AnotherAtExitAnimationCloser s (vecs.begin(), vecs.end())
```

Finally, with idiomatic C++ I don't think you need to use these tricks... You could store a vector of types `T`, which on destruction `~T` calls `fileWriter::closeAnimation`.

Comment: Note: when storing a range, make sure the collection it's based on survives as long as you need to use the range.

Answer (score 3):

`atexit` is a legacy C function, and not very adapted to C++.  You can
register more than one function with `atexit`, but all of them must be
`void (*)()`, no `boost::function` and no arguments.

In C++, most, if not all of `atexit`'s functionality has been subsumed
by the destructors of static objects.  In your case, I'd write something 
like:

```
#include <vector>

class CallInDestructor
{
    class Registry
    {
        std::vector<CallInDestructor*> myInstances;
    public:
        register_caller(CallInDestructor* caller)
        {
            myInstances.push_back(caller);
        }
        ~Registry()
        {
            while ( !myInstances.empty() ) {
                delete myInstances.back();
                myInstances.pop_back();
            }
        }
    };
    static Registry& registry()
    {
        static Registry theOneAndOnly;
        return theOneAndOnly;
    }

protected:
    CallInDestructor() { registry().register_caller( this ); }

public:
    virtual ~CallInDestructor() {}
};

template<typename Fnc> void callAtExit( Fnc fnc );

template<typename Fnc>
class ConcreteCallInDestructor : public CallInDestructor
{
    Fnc myFnc;
    ConcreteCallInDestructor( Fnc fnc = Fnc() ) : myFnc( fnc ) {}
    virtual ~ConcreteCallInDestructor() { myFnc(); }

    friend void callAtExit<Fnc>( Fnc fnc );
};

template<typename Fnc>
void
callAtExit( Fnc fnc )
{
    new ConcreteCallInDestructor<Fnc>( fnc );
}
```

Use `callAtExit` as you would `atexit`, but it should work for anything
which can be called with no arguments (including a `boost::function`).
Or you can write your own classes deriving from `CallInDestructor`, as
long as you take steps to ensure that all instances are dynamically
allocated (since the constructor registers the object so that it will be
deleted); these classes can contain any additional data you want.

Comment: It seems incredibly usefully. Why is it legacy? :-)

Comment: @Misha Because you can't pass it arguments, and because you don't need it in C++; just define a static variable whose destructor does whatever you want.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that bind returns a function object, and atexit takes a pointer to a function that returns void and takes no parameter.

You can try this:

```
void fun() {
    fileWriter::closeAnimation("0");
}

atexit(fun);
```

Comment: I suppose there are some workarounds such as having a vector full of the values that correspond to the strings, but I was hoping to do it in one line without further complicating my code :-)